# React Router - "ambiguous indirect export: Switch" error in App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I am building a React app using React Router, and I am getting an error "ambiguous indirect export: Switch" in my App component. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import About from './About';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // ... other styles
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {/* Displaying the header on all pages */}
        <div className={classes.greeting}>
          <Typography variant="h1">Welcome to the Fractals website!</Typography>
        </div>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {/* Displaying the home page with cards */}
            <Grid container justifyContent="center">
              {/* Card for the "Theory" page */}
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                {/* Adding a Link component to navigate to the "Theory" page */}
                <Link to="/theory" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                  {/* Rest of the card code remains the same */}
                </Link>
              </Grid>

              {/* Other cards follow the same pattern */}
              {/* ... */}
            </Grid>
          </Route>

          {/* Routes for the pages */}
          <Route path="/theory">
            {/* Component for the "Theory" page */}
            <Theory />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/serpinski">
            {/* Component for the "Sierpinski Triangle" page */}
            <Serpinski />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/mandelbrot">
            {/* Component for the "Mandelbrot Set" page */}
            <Mandelbrot />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I believe I have imported Switch correctly from `react-router-dom`, so I'm not sure what the issue is. How can I resolve this error and make my App component work properly with React Router?

I've updated to `react-router-dom@6` code using the `Routes` component instead of `Switch`, but still have issue rendering.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Mandelbrot from './Mandelbrot';
import Serpinski from './Serpinski';
import Theory from './Theory';

// Create styles using Material-UI
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // ... other styles
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {/* Display the header on all pages */}
        <div className={classes.greeting}>
          <Typography variant="h1">Welcome to the Fractals website!</Typography>
        </div>

        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {/* Display the main page with cards */}
            <Grid container justifyContent="center">
              {/* Card for the "Theory" page */}
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                {/* Add a Link component to navigate to the "Theory" page */}
                <Link to="/theory" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                  {/* The rest of the card's code remains unchanged */}
                </Link>
              </Grid>

              {/* Other cards are similar */}
              {/* ... */}
            </Grid>
          </Route>

          {/* Routes for the pages */}
          <Route path="/theory">
            {/* The "Theory" page component */}
            <Theory />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/serpinski">
            {/* The "Serpinski Triangle" page component */}
            <Serpinski />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/mandelbrot">
            {/* The "Mandelbrot Set" page component */}
            <Mandelbrot />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: @RubenSmn 5.3.4

Comment: That import looks fine for v5 react-router ... anything unusual in your package.json? Might try clearing out `node_modules/` and reinstalling the dependencies if you haven't already.

Comment: @motto error Missing list of packages to add to your project.

Comment: If you're using yarn then running `yarn` in your project directory should reinstall everything based on package.json

Comment: @motto nvm what about **ambiguous indirect export: Switch**

Comment: @Minesweeper If your dependencies are up to date all I could imagine is that your bundler / runtime is getting confused with CJS and ES modules, which is why I was wondering about your package.json, or stale dependencies. [This sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react17-legacy-mui-vsbk8h) doesn't have any problems with your snippet.

Comment: Note that the error isn't about what you explicitly import, it's that there's *some* ambiguous export of a `Switch` component somewhere. What version(s) of `react-router` and/or `react-router-dom` do you have ***installed*** (*not what you think you are using*). To check run in the terminal in the root project directory `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back what is actually installed. Please also [edit] to include your package.json file so we can see what versions you are trying to have installed.

Comment: @DrewReese```└─┬ react-router-dom@6.11.0
  └── react-router@6.11.0```

Comment: `react-router@6` replaced the `Switch` component with the `Routes` component. Are you wanting to stick to using `react-router-dom@5`?

Comment: @DrewReese im use 6.11.0 how can i fix this error

Comment: Do you want to continue using `react-router-dom@5` components, APIs, and syntax, or do you want to use `react-router-dom@6` components, APIs, and syntax? If the former then you should install the correct version, and if the latter you should [migrate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) to code from v5 to v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `react-router-dom@6.11.0` installed but you are importing a `Switch` component from `react-router-dom` which is a RRDv5 component export and was replaced in RRDv6 by the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component.

You basically have two options:

1. Install the correct version of `react-router-dom` for the components you want to import and use.

   First uninstall `react-router` and `react-router-dom`: `npm uninstall --save react-router react-router-dom`
   Install the latest RRDv5 dependency: `npm install --save react-router-dom@5`
2. [Migrate your code to `react-router-dom@6`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5).

   Import the `Routes` component to replace the `Switch`, and update the `Route` components to render their content on the `element` prop *as JSX*.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {
     BrowserRouter as Router,
     Route,
     Routes,
     Link
   } from 'react-router-dom';
   import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
   import {
     Card,
     CardMedia,
     CardContent,
     Typography,
     Grid
   } from '@material-ui/core';
   import About from './About';

   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     // ... other styles
   }));

   const App = () => {
     const classes = useStyles();

     return (
       <Router>
         <div>
           {/* Displaying the header on all pages */}
           <div className={classes.greeting}>
             <Typography variant="h1">
               Welcome to the Fractals website!
             </Typography>
           </div>

           <Routes>
             <Route
               path="/"
               element={(
                 {/* Displaying the home page with cards */}
                 <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                   {/* Card for the "Theory" page */}
                   <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                     {/* Adding a Link component to navigate
                       to the "Theory" page */}
                     <Link to="/theory" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                       {/* Rest of the card code remains the same */}
                     </Link>
                   </Grid>

                   {/* Other cards follow the same pattern */}
                   {/* ... */}
                 </Grid>
               )}
             />

             {/* Routes for the pages */}
             {/* Component for the "Theory" page */}
             <Route path="/theory" element={<Theory />} />

             {/* Component for the "Sierpinski Triangle" page */}
             <Route path="/serpinski" element={<Serpinski />} />

             {/* Component for the "Mandelbrot Set" page */}
             <Route path="/mandelbrot" element={<Mandelbrot />} />
           </Routes>
         </div>
       </Router>
     );
   };

   export default App;
   ```

Comment: ```Uncaught Error: [undefined] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>```

Comment: @Minesweeper *Somewhere* in your RRDv6 app code you are still rendering a (*undefined*) non-`Route` component in the `Routes` component.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a non-Route component being rendered in the Routes component in this RRDv6 app code. All components being rendered inside the Routes component are either Route components or Link components, which are valid for use inside Routes.

Comment: @Minesweeper Only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component, `Link` has to be rendered outside it. Can you update your post with the RRDv6 code you are rendering?

Comment: yes yes yes（＾∀＾●）ﾉｼ

Comment: @Minesweeper In the edit to your post, the code, none of the `Route` components are rendering their content on their `element` prop. Along with `Route` or `Fragment` being the only valid children of the `Routes` component, the only valid child of the `Route` component is another `Route` component in the case of nested routes. Take a closer look at my answer and note that `<Grid>...</Grid>` was moved into its route's `element` prop, same with `<Theory />`, `<Serpinski />`, and `<Mandelbrot />`.